# Error CV_8UC1 in function void adaptive threshold OpenCV android

Tags: android, eclipse, opencv, image-processing

I'm using OpenCV for my image processing Android OCR apps, I need to get binary image using adaptive threshold function by OpenCV, my code like shown below :

```
  String SourcePicture = cursor.getString(URIPicture);

  Bitmap ImagePicker = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(SourcePicture);
  Bitmap InputImagePicker = ImagePicker.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);

  Mat MatrixBitmapSmooth = Utils.bitmapToMat(InputImagePicker);                   
  Mat MatrixBitmapBiner = new Mat();
  Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(MatrixBitmapSmooth, MatrixBitmapBiner, 255,    
         Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 4);

  Bitmap BitmapBiner = null;
  Utils.matToBitmap(MatrixBitmapBiner, BitmapBiner);
  ImageInput.setImageBitmap(ImagePicker);
```

It looks like good, no error found at Eclipse, but when I run it on emulator,it give error "UNFORTUNATELY APPS HAS STOPPED WORKING", the log cat show :

```
05-12 01:09:55.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: /home/andreyk/OpenCV2/trunk/opencv_2.3.1.b2/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:555: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function void cv::adaptiveThreshold(const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_OutputArray&, double, int, int, int, double)
```

What's wrong with my code ??? if there is something wrong in my code ??? Would you help me please ???

**EDIT**

I've got advice from [Mr.Roger Rowland](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2065121/roger-rowland) that image input must a single channel grayscale image, so i edited my code like shown bellow :

```
String SourcePicture = cursor.getString(URIPicture);
Bitmap InputImagePicker = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(SourcePicture);

Mat MatrixBitmapSmooth = new 
        Mat(InputImagePicker.getWidth(),InputImagePicker.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
MatrixBitmapSmooth = Utils.bitmapToMat(InputImagePicker);                 

Mat MatrixBitmapBiner = new                
        Mat(InputImagePicker.getWidth(),InputImagePicker.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC1);
MatrixBitmapBiner = Utils.bitmapToMat(InputImagePicker);

Imgproc.cvtColor(MatrixBitmapBiner, MatrixBitmapBiner, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);
Imgproc.cvtColor(MatrixBitmapSmooth, MatrixBitmapSmooth, Imgproc.COLOR_BGR2GRAY); 
Imgproc.adaptiveThreshold(MatrixBitmapSmooth, MatrixBitmapBiner, 255,       
                        Imgproc.ADAPTIVE_THRESH_MEAN_C, Imgproc.THRESH_BINARY, 15, 8); 

Bitmap BitmapBiner = null;
Utils.matToBitmap(MatrixBitmapBiner, BitmapBiner);
BitmapBiner = BitmapBiner.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true);
ImageOutput.setImageBitmap(BitmapBiner);
```

The error logcat before disappear :

```
05-12 01:09:55.425: E/AndroidRuntime(1164): Caused by: CvException [org.opencv.core.CvException: /home/andreyk/OpenCV2/trunk/opencv_2.3.1.b2/modules/imgproc/src/thresh.cpp:555: error: (-215) src.type() == CV_8UC1 in function void cv::adaptiveThreshold(const cv::_InputArray&, const cv::_OutputArray&, double, int, int, int, double)
```

But then it show error it said :

```
05-14 00:18:40.252: E/AndroidRuntime(1371): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
```

Comment: The error is telling you that `adaptiveThreshold` expects a single-channel greyscale image as input, which is also [what the OpenCV documentation says](http://docs.opencv.org/modules/imgproc/doc/miscellaneous_transformations.html#adaptivethreshold).

Comment: I've edit my code, I add this code : Imgproc.cvtColor(MatrixBitmapBiner, MatrixBitmapBiner, Imgproc.COLOR_RGB2GRAY);.......... but it show error : "Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException",..... Just like my update question as shown above, thanks

Comment: Probably `BitmapBiner.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true)` is returning null - I'm guessing because conversion from greyscale to `ARGB_888` is not supported. Maybe you need to raise a new, specific question.

Comment: I already delete BitmapBiner.copy(Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888, true), then the result of ImageOutput.setImageBitmap(BitmapBiner);,.... it show nothing, what's wrong ???

Answer (score 0):

Also, create a 4 channel Mat.

```
Mat MatrixBitmapSmooth = new 
    Mat(InputImagePicker.getWidth(),InputImagePicker.getHeight(), CvType.CV_8UC4);
```

You need to convert RGBA to Gray. Use `COLOR_RGBA2GRAY`

After performing `adaptiveThreshold` if you are converting it back to bitmap, you might want to convert it back to RGBA so use `COLOR_GRAY2RGBA`